# Proof for expressive power of flow-based models: Normalizing Flows for Probabilistic Modeling and Inference by Papamakarios et al

Tags: mathematical-statistics, normalizing-flow

I've ben reading the great summary work on Normalising Flows "Normalizing Flows for Probabilistic Modeling and Inference" by Papamakarios et al..

A few questions regarding a proof came up as I read section 2.2 on "Expressive power of flow-based models", the proof starts on page 4.

Right at the start, it is assumed that $p_x(\textbf{x}) > 0$ for all $\textbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I don't see how this is a reasonable assumption. How can a random variable have positive probability over the whole of $\mathbb{R}^D$?

Secondly, the assumption that the conditional probability be differentiable w.r.t. $(x_i, \textbf{x}_{<i})$ is later used to conclude that a function $F(x_i, \textbf{x}_{<i})$ is differentiable. Wouldn't we need to assume continuous differiantibility w.r.t. the inputs for that to hold?

Comment: On *"it is assumed that $p_x(\mathbf{x}) > 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I don't see how this is a reasonable assumption,"* the authors refer to $p_x(\mathbf{x})$ as a (target) probability density of a random vector $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^D$. I am therefore unable to understand why $p_x(\mathbf{x}) > 0$ for all $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^D$ would be problematic, please may you clarify?

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I'm no mathematician, so maybe I'm misunderstanding something obvious. But, for e.g. $D = 1$, to me it seems impossible to have a well defined density with $p_x(\textbf{x}) > 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. The integral over that densitiy would not converge, or would it?

Comment: I am no mathematician either. But I understand *well-defined continuous probability density* to mean that the PDF must obey $p_X(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}} p_X(x) \space dx = 1$. I see no reason why instead imposing the strict inequality $p_X(x) > 0$ would mean that $p$ is no longer well-defined. For example, consider the standard normal r.v. $Z \sim N(0,1)$, with PDF $$p_Z(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} \exp \left(-\frac{1}{2}z^2 \right).$$ Note that $p_Z(z) > 0$ for all $z \in \mathbb{R}$, but we still have $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} p_Z(z) \space dz =1$.

Comment: You're absolutely right, thanks. I've mixed up probability densities and probabilites. Now the assumption makes perfect sense!